# Numpy exponential not working as it should

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I wrote this simple code on Python:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-400,400,80)
y = np.exp(-1/35*np.absolute(x))

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Here is the graph I got:

[image]

Why is it doing the calculations wrong?
I did the same graph using Octave:

[image]

Can anyone help me out, please?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I get a similar plot, albeit with a flat top because of the spacing of the points produced by linspace. It looks like you are actually using y = np.exp(-x), without the 35.

Comment: @aquirdturtle -- I believe that is because OP uses python2 and you use python3.

Comment: Ah, perhaps, I am indeed using python3. Although if I use y = np.exp(-x), this perfectly reproduces his plot, so this is also potentially linked to the error.

Answer (score 1):

You are using integer arithmetic when you meant to use floating-point.

Try this:

```
y = np.exp(-1.0/35*np.absolute(x))
```

In Python2, `<int>/<int>` yields a rounded-down integer. In Python3, the same expression yields a floating-point value.

Other ways to accomplish this same result are:

- `y = np.exp(float(1)/35*np.absolute(x))`
- `from __future__ import division` ... `y = np.exp(1/35*np.absolute(x))`
- Use Python3.

Comment: I use `from __future__ import division` at the start of programs to prevent this.  Switching to python 3 is another options.

Comment: How big is the difference between python 3 and python 2.7?